# PHP/Mysql authentication

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Let us say I want to to authenticate users with a PHP application. If the database is just going to be used by company workers, to which privileges will be assigned in the Mysql.user table by me, I think my php login code should just use the Mysql.user table for user authentication, I think I have no need to create another user table ? Also if I create another user table then I have to php code for a permission scheme myself for individual users ? In what situations should one use the Mysql.user table for authentication ? and what situations should one create a separate table for user authentication ? I was somewhat confused about this...

Thanks
Jillian

Comment: You don't give much to work with, but you could create an extra field in your database where you can give the user a number which represents an authorization level.

Comment: It's worth investigating if using a simple [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) would help with this, as many come with a built-in authentication system that does this in a secure way. For example, [Laravel's authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/security) is quite robust out of the box. If you do it yourself you will have to be extremely careful to [follow the rules](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security). Please, **do not** use the MySQL users table for application authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what are the reasons not to use the MYSQL users table for application authentication ?  The advantage i see is permissions can be assigned easily in MYSQL and I can control what a particular user does on the database. Is it better to reproduce that in the application code as mentioned by Daniel.